# ajax call based on '#' in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to input  strings in a `contenteditable div` and based on `"#" in a string` ,go for ajax call .

1) If `'#' comes as first character as user input`, go for ajax call.

2) If   whitespace/tab comes before `'#', go for ajax call

3) If user inputs a string and places cursor manually in between of string and provide whitespace followed by '#' and then whitespace, go for ajax call.

## .html

```
<div contenteditable="true" onkeyup="detectHash($event)"></div>
```

## .js

```
function detectHash(event){
var input = event.target.innerText.trim();

// check above conditions (1),(2),(3), conditons true,
// go for ajax call

$().ajax({
success:function(){

}
}}


}
```

Comment: And you are posting this question again why exactly?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt do you have a link to the previously asked question?

Comment: @freedomn-m that has been deleted already

Comment: Not clear what "at its back position" means - do you mean with space before/after?  *and* # as last character?  So not just # at start or # at end?  Please provide examples for each of your rules.  Seems straight forward, but the rules are confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex to pass these rules:

> 1) If '#' comes as first character as user input, go for ajax call.
>
> 2) If whitespace/tab comes before `'#', go for ajax call

(3 is the same as 2)

Rule 1:  `^#`  `^` = start of line

Rule 2:  `\s#` `\s` = any whitespace, including tab

Example snippet, these can be combined into a single regex, but left as separate for demonstration (as with noajax/goajax classes - for the snippet only)

```js
$("div").on("input", detectHash);

function detectHash(event) {
    var input = event.target.innerText.trim();
    if (input.match(/^#/) || input.match(/\s#/))
    {
        $("#out").removeClass("noajax").addClass("goajax");        
    } else {
        $("#out").removeClass("goajax").addClass("noajax");
    }
}
```

```css
div#inp { border:1px solid #ccc; height:200px; width:200px; }
div.noajax { background-color: red; height:5px; width:200px; }
div.goajax { background-color: green; height:5px; width:200px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='inp' contenteditable="true"></div>
<div id='out' class="noajax"></div>
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `.indexof` but might need an extra if you also need to check for tabs, whereas `.match` with `\s` handles this for you.

```
if (input.indexOf("#") === 0 || input.indexOf(" #") >= 0)
```

Comment: rule 3 is the same as rule 2 because if you check for " #" it will be found before you can check for " # "